# Поиск всех наиболее часто встречающихся значений списка. Как можно улучшить/оптимизировать код?

Tags: python, классы, инспекция-кода

Изучаю потихоньку статистику, в качестве практики и в целях закрепления пишу функции для вычисления некоторых простых значений. Суть такова: нужно найти моду (наиболее часто встречающееся значение) выборки и вернуть это значение. Если значений в таком кол-ве несколько - вернуть все. Я написал код, он работает, но писал "в лоб" и мое решение кажется мне топорным и костыльным. Подскажите как можно его оптимизировать.

```
class Sample(list):
    """ Класс Выборка, основанный на стандартном list """

    def mode(self):
        """ Возвращает значение моды выборки (всех мод, если их несколько) """
        from collections import Counter
        mode_list = []                               # список мод
        x = Counter(self).most_common()[0][0]
        mode_list.append(x)
        counter = Counter(self).most_common()[0][1]  # сколько раз встречается эта мода в выборке
        while True:
            while x in self:
                self.remove(x)
            if Counter(self).most_common()[0][1] == counter:  # до тех пор, пока в выборке
                x = Counter(self).most_common()[0][0]         # есть значения в таком же кол-ве
                mode_list.append(x)                           # ищем следующее значение
            else:
                break                           # в противном случае прекращаем поиск
        return mode_list
```

тесты:

```
a = Sample([3, 15, 22, 3, 41, 11, 15, 21, 21, 21])
b = Sample([3, 15, 22, 3, 41, 11, 15, 21, 21])
c = Sample(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one'])

print(a.mode(), b.mode(), c.mode(), sep='\n')

# [21]
# [3, 15, 21]
# ['one']
```

Comment: Для получения **любого одного** значения вы могли бы реализовать метод `any_mode = lambda self: max(self, key=self.count)` с помощью встроенной функции [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), а также метода [`list.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). 
Учтите также, что если вы реализуете методы, возвращающие часть объекта типа `Sample`, то и результат лучше возвращать в типе `Sample`.

Comment: Помимо `Counter` модуль `collections` содержит [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) с которым весьма удобно производить аккумулирующие вычисления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Класс здесь не нужен, вообще. Нужна просто функция, применяющаяся к списку.
   К обязательному прочтению: [**Перестаньте писать классы**](https://habr.com/ru/post/140581/)
2. Лучше не вызывать `Counter` по десять раз. Вы постоянно пересчитывать сколько встречается каждый элемент списка, а нужно всего лишь пройтись циклом результату вызова метода `most_common()`, пока у всех элементов одинаковое количество.
3. Очень редко при обработке данных действительно нужно менять исходную последовательность - вместо этого обычно формируют новую.

Пример реализации:

```
from collections import Counter

def mode(x):
    if not x:  # Сразу проверяем, что исходный список не пустой
        return []
    else:
        most_common = Counter(x).most_common()
        max_count = most_common[0][1]
        result = []
        for x, count in most_common:
            if count < max_count:
                break
            else:
                result.append(x)
        return result

print(mode([3, 15, 22, 3, 41, 11, 15, 21, 21, 21]))  # [21]
print(mode([3, 15, 22, 3, 41, 11, 15, 21, 21]))  # [3, 15, 21]
print(mode(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']))  # ['one']
```

Более "продвинутая" реализация этой же функции:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def mode(x):
    most_common = Counter(x).most_common()
    if not most_common:
        return []
    else:
        max_count = most_common[0][1]
        return [x for x, count in takewhile(lambda x: x[1]==max_count, most_common)]
```

Метод `takewhile` (буквально "брать пока...") возвращает из последовательности элементы, пока функция от элемента возвращает истину - в данном случае пока количество каждого элемента равно максимальному количеству. А дальше просто от каждой пары значение-количество берется только значение, и из этих значений уже формируется список.

Comment: У меня в этом классе намного больше методов реализовано, просто привёл только один, по которому вопрос, да и это больше для себя, для практики. А так ваш код подходит, спасибо

Comment: @whizz169 2 и 3 пункты все равно остаются в силе. Например, ваш вариант метода менял исходную последовательность. Как после этого можно вообще к ней применить еще какой-то метод?

Answer (score 0):

А можно еще проще, вообще без каких-либо дополнительных библиотек, на базовом Python

```
def mode(arr):
    MD=[]
    elem_dict={}
    for elem in set(arr):
        elem_dict[elem] = arr.count(elem)
    for key in elem_dict.keys(): 
        if (elem_dict[key] == max(elem_dict.values())): 
            MD.append([key, elem_dict[key]])
    return MD


print(mode(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one'])) # [['one', 2]]
print(mode([3, 15, 22, 3, 41, 11, 15, 21, 21])) # [[3, 2], [15, 2], [21, 2]]
print(mode([3, 15, 22, 3, 41, 11, 15, 21, 21, 21]))  # [[21, 3]]
```

Comment: По условию не нужно возвращать количество.

Comment: Ну, тогда еще проще - заменяется последняя строка в теле функции: MD.append(key)